# Не устанавливается pip в venv

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, virtualenv

Я создал виртуальное окружение командами

```
virtualenv -p python3 venv 
source venv/bin/activate
```

и пытаюсь установить pip в этом окружении

```
 pip3 install requests
Collecting requests
  Using cached requests-2.26.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1
  Using cached urllib3-1.26.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Using cached certifi-2021.5.30-py2.py3-none-any.whl (145 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer~=2.0.0; python_version >= "3"
  Using cached charset_normalizer-2.0.5-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5; python_version >= "3"
  Using cached idna-3.2-py3-none-any.whl (59 kB)
Installing collected packages: urllib3, certifi, charset-normalizer, idna, requests
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ubuntu/pipeline/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3-1.26.6.dist-info'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Пробовал, используя user:

```
pip3 install requests --user
ERROR: Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.
```

Использовал sudo:

```
sudo pip3 install requests
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (2.22.0)
```

В чем проблема? Как установить pip

Comment: Он разве не по умолчанию летит? Загляните в env/bin/. Посмотрел, он у вас есть. Мне кажется, что вы что то не договариваете. Вы устанавливаете все зависимости из файла? requirements.txt?

Comment: @ipatev_nn так товарищ может sudo использовать я смотрю. И когда он повторно пытается установить requests, pip отвечает, что пакет уже есть. Используйте sudo без user

Comment: @Dmitry я попытался выполнить скрипт, но заметил, что pip не установлен. Посмотрел pip list, а там практически никаких pip нет. Я попытался установить requests, но тут ошибка

Comment: @Dmitry в `venv/bin` у меня нет

Comment: Вы же используете `source venv/bin/activate`, то есть venv/bin существует

Answer (score 0):

Ответ в комментарии я не получил. Повангуем.

Проблема могла возникнуть по причине установки сразу нескольких пакетов, например так:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

и один из них выкинул ошибку. Такое случается часто у невнимательных
или ленивых разработчиков, когда переносят окружение с windows на linux. И пакеты для винды попадают в список зависимостей.

Получилось так, что пакеты закешировались, но не установились и через `pip freeze` их не увидеть.

Что можно сделать:

1. Заглянуть в кэш pip'a

```
python -m pip cache list
```

2. Если мои догадки верны, то лист будет содержать все ваши пакеты. Их можно удалить все из кэша, либо по отдельности

```
python -m pip cache remove
```

3. И повторить установку пакетов по отдельности, либо без того, котоый не хочет устанавливаться

[документация](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_cache/) по работе с кэшем pip.

И дополнительный вариант. Из requirements.txt удалить конфликтующий пакет, повторить установку без него. А затем уже колдовать с только с ним.

Естественно, что все манипуляции с активным виртуальным окружением

Comment: python3 -m pip cache list
ERROR: unknown command "cache" - maybe you meant "check"

Comment: Просто python, не python3 в виртуальном пространстве